# Menu Bar Animation Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, beginner, css, plugin

I'm fairly new to JS/jQuery (a few months), and I think it's time to start getting involved in the community. So I wrote a little plugin. Nothing revolutionary. Really, the project is to write a clean, workable plugin. Any and all thoughts and suggestions on how I can make the code cleaner, or the animations smoother, or anything, are very much appreciated.

Here's the plugin in action: http://jsfiddle.net/VA7P5/

Here is the plugin code:

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.menuBar = function (options) { 

    var defaults = {

        width: 145, // Width of Sidebar
        left: true, // If true, sidebar is positioned left. If false, it's positioned right
        height: 80, // Height of footer
        barColor: '#000', // Color of three-bar menu before it's opened
        menuBackground: '#303030', // Background color of sidebar and footer
        closeColor: '#fff' // Color of close-button
    };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function () {

        var i = $(this);
        var o = options;
        var width = $('nav.sidebar').css('width');
        var height = $('footer.hidden').css('height');
        var closeColor = $('.bar').css('background');
        var barColor = $('.bar').css('background');
        var barOne = $('.menu-bar-top');
        var barTwo = $('.menu-bar-bottom');
        var barThree = $('.menu-bar-mid');
        var menuTrigger = $('nav.sidebar a');
        var fadeWrapper = $('#fade-wrapper');
        var nav = $('nav.sidebar');
        var footerHidden  = $('footer.hidden');
        var bar = $('.bar');

        bar.css('background', o.barColor);

        if (o.left) {
            nav.css({
                'width': o.width,
                'left': o.width - (o.width * 2),
                'background': o.menuBackground
            });
            $('.menu-trigger').css({
                'left': 0
            });
        } else {
            nav.css({
                'width': o.width,
                'right': o.width - (o.width * 2),
                'background': o.menuBackground
            });
            $('.menu-trigger').css({
                'right': 0
            });
        }

        footerHidden.css({
            'height': o.height,
            'bottom': o.height - (o.height * 2), 
            'background': o.menuBackground
        });

        i.click(function(){
            if (i.hasClass('open')) {

                closeMenu();
                i.removeClass('open');

                // Allow scrolling again when menu is closed
                $('body').css('overflow', '');

            } else {

                openMenu();
                i.addClass('open');

                // No scrolling while menu is open
                $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');

            }
        });

        $('#fade-wrapper').click(function(){
            closeMenu();
            i.removeClass('open');
            $('body').css('overflow', '');
        });


/*===========================================================================================================
                                      Opening/Closing Functions
===========================================================================================================*/

        function openMenu() {
            fadeWrapper.fadeIn(100, function(){
                barOne.css({
                    'top': '8px',
                    'transform': 'rotate(405deg)',
                    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(405deg)',
                    '-moz-transform': 'rotate(405deg)',
                    '-ms-transform': 'rotate(405deg)',
                    '-o-transform': 'rotate(405deg)'
                });

                barTwo.css({
                    'top': '8px',
                    'transform': 'rotate(-405deg)',
                    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(-405deg)',
                    '-moz-transform': 'rotate(-405deg)',
                    '-ms-transform': 'rotate(-405deg)',
                    '-o-transform': 'rotate(-405deg)'
                });
                if (o.left) {
                    nav.animate({'left': '+=' + o.width}, 200);
                } else {
                    nav.animate({'right': '+=' + o.width}, 200);
                }
                footerHidden.animate({'bottom': '+=' + o.height}, 200);
                barThree.fadeOut(100);
                bar.css('background', o.closeColor);
            });
        }

        function closeMenu() {
            setTimeout(function(){
                barThree.fadeTo(100, 1);
                fadeWrapper.fadeOut(100);
                if (o.left) {
                    nav.animate({'left': '-=' + o.width}, 200);
                } else {
                    nav.animate({'right': '-=' + o.width}, 200);
                }
                footerHidden.animate({'bottom': '-=' + o.height}, 200);
                bar.css('background', o.barColor);

                barOne.css({
                    'top': '3px',
                    'transform': 'rotate(360deg)',
                    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(360deg)',
                    '-moz-transform': 'rotate(360deg)',
                    'ms-transform': 'rotate(360deg)',
                    'o-transform': 'rotate(360deg)'
                });

                barTwo.css({
                    'top': '13px',
                    'transform': 'rotate(-360deg)',
                    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(-360deg)',
                    '-moz-transform': 'rotate(-360deg)',
                    '-ms-transform': 'rotate(-360deg)',
                    '-o-transform': 'rotate(-360deg)'
                });}, 1);
        }
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

The necessary HTML:

```
<nav class="sidebar">
        <a class="menu cursor" title="Menu">
            <div class="menu-trigger">
                <div class="bar-container">
                    <div class="bar menu-bar-top"></div>
                    <div class="bar menu-bar-mid"></div>
                    <div class="bar menu-bar-bottom"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <!-- Sidebar content goes here -->
    </nav>

    <div id="fade-wrapper"></div>

    <footer class="hidden">
        <!-- Footer content goes here -->
    </footer>
```

The necessary CSS:

```
a.cursor {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#fade-wrapper {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: 5000;
}

nav.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.menu-trigger {
    position: fixed;
    top: 8px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.bar-container {
    margin-top: 3px;
    height: 13px;
}

.bar {
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 90%;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.menu-bar-top {
    top: 3px;
    left: 2px;
}

.menu-bar-mid {
    top: 8px;
    left: 2px;
}

.menu-bar-bottom {
    top: 13px;
    left: 2px;
}

footer.hidden {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your code, it is easy to follow, has comments, well named variables etc. The only thing I would point out is that you are repeating yourself here and there. So I will focus on that:

- This piece of code:

  ```
  if (o.left) {
      nav.css({
          'width': o.width,
          'left': o.width - (o.width * 2),
          'background': o.menuBackground
      });
      $('.menu-trigger').css({
          'left': 0
      });
  } else {
      nav.css({
          'width': o.width,
          'right': o.width - (o.width * 2),
          'background': o.menuBackground
      });
      $('.menu-trigger').css({
          'right': 0
      });
  }
  ```

  Is really repeating the same thing but with `left` being replaced with `right`, you could just assign `left` or `right` to a variable first.

  ```
  var key = o.left ? 'left' : 'right';
   nav.css({
       'width': o.width,
       'background': o.menuBackground
   }).css( key, o.width - (o.width * 2) );
   $('.menu-trigger').css( key , 0 );
  ```
- This piece of code is repeated a few times at well, the only different is the degrees and the value of `'top'`.

  ```
  barTwo.css({
      'top': '13px',
      'transform': 'rotate(-360deg)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(-360deg)',
      '-moz-transform': 'rotate(-360deg)',
      '-ms-transform': 'rotate(-360deg)',
      '-o-transform': 'rotate(-360deg)'
  });}, 1);
  ```

  You could consider a helper function that this transformation for you

  ```
  function generateTransformation( top , transformation ){
      return {
          'top': top,
          'transform': transformation,
          '-webkit-transform': transformation,
          '-moz-transform': transformation,
          '-ms-transform': transformation,
          '-o-transform': transformation'              
      };
  }
  ```

  Then, you can simply do

  ```
  barOne.css( generateTransformation( '3px'  , 'rotate(360deg)'  ));
  barTwo.css( generateTransformation( '13px' , 'rotate(-360deg)' ));
  ```
- These:

  ```
  if (o.left) {
      nav.animate({'left': '+=' + o.width}, 200);
  } else {
      nav.animate({'right': '+=' + o.width}, 200);
  }
  ```

  I will leave to you as an exercise for the reader.
- `var bar = $('.bar');` <- This will select 3 bars, perhaps call it `bars` ?
- `var closeColor = $('.bar').css('background');` <- This takes the background color of the first bar, I would put that in a comment or make it more obvious by calling `$('.bar').eq(0).css('background');` or even better determine `bars` first and then go for `bars.eq(0).css('background');`

Comment: Thanks a ton! This kind of feedback is exactly what I'm looking for. I want to post an update, but before I do: Should I A) replace the code in the original post with the new code, B) Add the new code block to the original post or C) post the new code block as an answer?

Comment: You are welcome, Option C is the way to go.

Comment: I just posted the update. I've got a quick question, though: Why is it that `elem.css(var, var)` works, but `elem.css({var: var})` does not?

Comment: Gah, I meant Option D -> New Question, my bad, I misread your options

Comment: For your question: because in the 2nd statement it does not evaluate `var`, it just uses the string `var` as the key, because that is how JS Object Notation works.

Comment: Ah. I guess I failed to see that `elem.css({...})` was object notation. One more question: Is there a way to achieve a 405deg rotation every time `openMenu()` fires and only a 45deg rotation every time `closeMenu()` fires? As it is, you only get the 405deg rotation the very first time `openMenu()` fires.

Comment: Last comment, though feel free to ask questions in Chat ( http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor ) by addressing @Konijn, that would really be an SO question, I cant tell off hand what is going on.